# Why is JSON.stringify() slow for large objects

Tags: javascript, json, stringify

I am trying to understand about `JSON.stringify()` and often times I hear people saying that its very slow for large objects. So I would like to understand what makes `JSON.stringify` so slow.

After researching on the Internet,  I found that the alternative to JSON.stringify() is a module called `fast-json-stringify` which uses a schema based technique to stringify objects.

Could you please explain how a schema based technique outperforms `JSON.stringify()`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Form [fast-json-stringify README.md](https://github.com/fastify/fast-json-stringify): "fast-json-stringify is significantly faster than JSON.stringify() **for small payloads**. Its performance advantage shrinks as your payload grows." (emphasize mine).

Comment: I recently noticed the extreme slowness of V8's JSON.stringify for objects with large string values - I've posted a chromium issue about it here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1473638

Answer (score 4):

`JSON.stringify` is a cpu bound operation.

The object subject to `JSON.stringify` needs to be parsed and then be transferred into an external memory block during the current thread. (heavily blocking Object:Get / Has / IsThatType or NULL / memory allocations etc) When the 'stringify' is completed, the result must be copied back to current heap. (not for free - blocks the main thread again)

Comment: So... *"how a schema based technique outperforms JSON.stringify()"*?